# How do I remove the remaining part of a word in the shell?

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

I would like to know if there is a key binding for removing the remaining part of a **word** in the shell.

Here I mean "remaining" as what stays on the *right-side* of the line cursor.

Example (`_|_` is the cursor):

```
> mv _|_john.csv ~/.hidden
... CTRL-something ...
> mv ~/.hidden
```

A sort of "light" version for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> (which drops the whole trailing chars 'til newline).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`bash` uses `readline(3)` for line editing that defines only alphanumerics as word constituent characters.

Now, the key-binding for kill-ing the next word is `M-d` if you are from the `emacs` world i.e. use <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>.

Now, as `john.csv` is composed of two words by definition, so you need to press the keys twice.

Comment: Thanks to both, choosing this one as official answer for it is slighlty more complete. ALT-D is definitely the most handy (for me).

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd> will remove the remaining part of a word. But as a `.` ends the word you'll need to press it two times to remove `john.csv`.

Comment: [Alt-D](http://img.thedailywtf.com/images/remy/foreveralone.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

If you have set your editing mode to `vi` (with `set -o vi`),
you can use the **d**elete command. 
First, type <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get into command mode. 
Then `dw` will delete a short word —
either a sequence of consecutive alphanumeric characters,
or a sequence of consecutive non-alphanumeric (non-blank) characters,
whichever comes first. 
In your example, if you type `dw`,
it will delete `john` and leave you with `mv _|_.csv ~/.hidden`. 
A second `dw` will delete the **`.`**,
and a third will delete `csv`   (i.e., `csv` and the space after it).

If the “word” (filename) to be deleted is short enough
that you can readily count the short words it comprises,
you can streamline this by typing `3dw`. 
But probably the better solution is to type `dW` (with a capital “W”)
to delete a long word —
a sequence of consecutive non-blank characters
(without regard to whether they are alphanumeric)
***and*** the following sequence of consecutive blanks.

Comment: thanks G-Man, but I meant how to do this directly in a live shell, not file editing. !!

Comment: This is not file editing; it *does* work in a live shell.  Try this: Type `set -o vi` and Enter.  Then type `ls fubar foo bar` (no Enter), press Esc, and type `3bdw`.  Your *live* command line now contains `ls foo bar`, and you can hit Enter to execute that.